# How to remove C/C++ and complete CDT from Eclipse?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have configured C/C++ in Eclipse kepler using CDT. But it didn't compile anyhow. But now I want to remove all the C/C++ configurations and the CDT from my eclipse, because now I do not need it. As well as I see the eclipse has been so very slow after configuring CDT. SO can somebody please tell me how to remove CDT and C/C++ from eclipse kepler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to **Help->About Eclipse Platform->Installation Details**

select the package you no longer want, and click uninstall. then restart.

if unsure what to install, then I'd suggest going to **Help->Install New Software** and browsing the CDT download-site to see what you have installed.

CDT Download Site: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler

[image]

and yes, the bracketeer plugin has a cat for its icon. priceless.